# Python: NoneType object has no attribute __getitem__. But its not nonetype

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nonetype

So I have this piece of code:

```
    key = val_cfg['src_model']
    print "key: ", key
    print "objects dict: ", objects
    print "before Nonetype"
    print "accessing objects dict: ", objects[key]  # line 122
    print "after"
    method = self._handle_object(
        val_cfg, objects[val_cfg['src_model']])
```

So the output I get is this:

```
key:  ir.model.data
objects dict:  {'res.partner': res.partner(22,), 'ir.model.data': ir.model.data()}
before Nonetype
accessing objects dict:  ir.model.data()
after
```

And then I get error:

```
_report.tests.test_vat_report: `   File "/home/user/addons/account_vat_report/models/vat_report.py", line 122, in _handle_method
2016-10-03 11:32:44,863 31650 ERROR vat_reports openerp.addons.account_vat_report.tests.test_vat_report: `     print "accessing objects dict: ", objects[key]
2016-10-03 11:32:44,863 31650 ERROR vat_reports openerp.addons.account_vat_report.tests.test_vat_report: ` TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Well this does not make sense. I print results of line 122, but test fails, saying its NoneType object. How so? I'm probably missing something here. Does someone see whats wrong here?

**Update**.
definition of `_handle_object`:

```
@api.model
def _handle_object(self, val_cfg, obj):
    """Method to get value from object."""
    # check if value is list or tuple of strings.
    if not isinstance(val_cfg['value'], basestring):
        for val in val_cfg['value']:
            value = self._get_attribute(obj, val_cfg['value'])
            # return first value that was retrieved.
            if value:
                return value
        # if we do not get any "True" value, just return last
        # one.
        else:
            return value
    else:
        return self._get_attribute(obj, val_cfg['value'])
```

Comment: Can u show the definition of your `self._handle_object` method? at lest the parameters

Comment: @Nf4r sure, just a sec. The strange thing, is it works with all other unittests just fine. Now I was actually writing another unittest, that happens to also call this method and it fails in this weird way.

Comment: Well, It seems like this is not enough for me without seeing the rest of the code (`get_attr` and `handle_method`) to find the solution, but it look like at some point the None is being passed as an `objects` into `_handle_method` method which results in this error. The best way is just to run debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I made stupid mistake, though that error got me confused, because of traceback. So I was looking in a wrong direction.

The problem was in another method, that is used to update objects dictionary. Its purpose is to update value for specific key, if some current iter item (from iteration) needs to be assigned if specified in configuration.

Anyway, the problem was this (in another method called `_set_dynamic_rows_data`):

```
objects = self._update_objects_dict(
                        val_cfg, objects, iter_)
```

I accidentally assigned `objects` dict to this method and because this method does not return anything, `objects` dict would be set to `None`. And it was disguised with that error, because first iteration, everything would be OK and during second iteration, when `objects` dict would be changed, it then would start failing like described in question.